# Using encoding/xml.Encoder how do I place the xml header on its own line?

Tags: xml, go

I have the following code that uses `xml.Encode`.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Stuff struct {
    Name string `xml:"name"`
}

func main() {
    w := &bytes.Buffer{}
    enc := xml.NewEncoder(w)
    enc.Indent("", "  ")
    procInst := xml.ProcInst{
        Target: "xml",
        Inst:   []byte("version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\""),
    }
    if err := enc.EncodeToken(procInst); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := enc.Encode(Stuff{"My stuff"}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(w.String())
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/ZtZ5FGABmj

It prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Stuff>
  <name>My stuff</name>
</Stuff>
```

How do I make it print with the `<Stuff>` start tag on a new line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Stuff>
  <name>My stuff</name>
</Stuff>
```

Unfortunately I need to write more here so that I can submit the question. Not really sure what to write though because I believe my question is summarized adequately with the above explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just write that one static line with a newline character yourself? [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/o_wEL-Fdca)

```
w := &bytes.Buffer{}
w.Write([]byte("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"))

enc := xml.NewEncoder(w)
enc.Indent("", "  ")
if err := enc.Encode(Stuff{"My stuff"}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(w.String())
```

This one line is even defined as a [constant](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#pkg-constants) in the `xml` package, so you can simply write: [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/gdDC8xF0NA)

```
w := &bytes.Buffer{}
w.WriteString(xml.Header)
```

Comment: Thanks that works great. I wonder if it is a bug that `EncodeToken` doesn't respect Indent?

Comment: For convenience, you can use `xml.Header` const from the package: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#pkg-constants. Here's how I solved the same problem in relation to this answer: https://gist.github.com/4f19c2981932caa71cd45fd9e6a21f61